# Is there a way to make suspend by closing the lid ALWAYS possible on a Samsung NC10?

Tags: 11.04, suspend, samsung

recently I installed Natty on a Samsung NC10 netbook. Most of the time, suspend by closing the lid works. But sometimes it just stays in its current state. Going to suspend by accessing the menu seems to work always on the other hand.

So is there a way to make suspend work on closing the lid always as well?

**Edit**: Additional information:

In the power management, both cases (battery and power line) are set to "suspend" when closing lid. 
The only things in the pm-suspend.log that don't look right are: 
`Having NetworkManager put all interaces to sleep...Failed.` and 
`Failed to connect to wpa_supplicant - wpa_ctrl_open: No such file or directory` However, suspending seems to go on after that.

**After a failed suspend attempt** by closing the lid attempt, **nothing new** is written to pm-suspend.log. The only new (shown bold there) thing in logs is `[drm] Big FIFO is enabled` in syslog and kern.log.

However, resume always works as well as suspend from power-indicator-button top right. It would be great when closing the lid would do just the *same*.

Comment: Does this happen while on AC power only, battery power only, or both?

Comment: it happens in both situations occasionally. (that's why my answer needed long time...)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this happens always when you are either on AC power or on battery:

Hit the  key and start typing `power management` (`po` is probably enough) and when you see it comming up in the results hit enter.

You will see 3 tabs. 2 of them are important for your question:

1. One for when on AC power:

[image: powermanagementAC]

2. and one for when on battery power:

[image: powermanagementBATTERY]

Both have an action set here for "When laptop lid is closed" (hence ændrük's comment).

If both are not set to 'suspend' you have your answer: change it to 'suspend'.

If this is not the issue you probably found a bug. I have seen some bugs related to suspend and several netbooks (including yours) but these are old. Have a look in your log files and see if it shows any errors when suspend does not work.

Same way as looking at `power management`: hit the  key and start typing `log file viewer`. When it shows up scroll down to `pm-suspend.log` and check this file for errors.

[image: pmsuspendlog]

You are looking for lines like these but then with errors:

```
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave resume suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging resume suspend:

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging resume suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change resume suspend:

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change resume suspend: success.
Fri May 13 18:27:31 CEST 2011: Finished.
```

If there are any please add these to your question.

Comment: Thanks Rinzwind! IN the power management, both cases are set to "suspend". The only thing in the pm-suspend.log that don't look right are: "Having NetworkManager put all interaces to sleep...Failed." and "Failed to connect to wpa_supplicant - wpa_ctrl_open: No such file or directory" However, suspending seems to go on after that. After a failed suspend by closing the lid attempt, NOTHING new is written to pm-suspend.log. The only new (bold) thing in logs is "[drm] Big FIFO is enabled" in syslog and kern.log. however, resume always works as well as suspend from power-indicator-button top right.